# How do you route to vanilla php scripts in Symfony4?

Tags: symfony, controller

I found a great library that I want to use (https://github.com/pqina/filepond-server-php) but it it's just a bunch of vanilla php scripts, some classes, some not.

They work fine but I don't know how to integrate it into my Symfony 4 application since the autoloader expects everything to be in class form, with the class name matching the file name.  Also parsing it all out and putting it into controller classes would take forever.

So I just manually placed this https://github.com/pqina/filepond-server-php into a folder in my project called "filepond", so it's literally like (I took out the files/folders I don't need):

[image]

I don't know how to route to a folder outside /src (and specifically route to a non-controller-class vanilla script like an index.php), to execute this code when it is called.  Is this even possible (to route to and execute vanilla php scripts within your Symfony project)?

Answer (score 0):

To reach file outside src you could update your `composer.json` autoload configuration. If your class is inside `filepond/Helper` you should add this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": ["src", "filepond/Helper"]
    }
}
```

In this case whenever you try to load a class, the autoloader try to find it inside src and then inside "filepond/Helper". But you should rename classes with the pattern

```
CLASS_NAME.php
```

An example:

If you have a class called with `Foo\Bar\Fizz\Buzz` there should be a file in

- `src/Foo/Bar/Fizz/Buzz.php`
- `filepond/Helper/Foo/Bar/Fizz/Buzz.php`

Alternatively, ... just load `FilePond.class.php` in your front controller. Same place where you symfony app is loaded.

Comment: Hi sensorario, it's a bunch of non-class functions and classes mixed together and calling each other back-and-forth, if I have to re-write it so that everything is in that class format then it's not worth it, I don't have the time. I was just wondering if you could hit the index.php via a router and let it do it's magic.